# How to use the ViewBag to store an array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to store a set of strings into the ViewBag in my Controller for use in my view. I want to be able to do this:

```
ViewBag.Autobots[0].FirstName = "Bumble"
ViewBag.Autobots[0].LastName = "Bee"
ViewBag.Autobots[1].FirstName = "Optimus"
ViewBag.Autobots[1].LastName = "Prime"
```

However, in order to do this I need to first declare the Autobots array.  I've tried a few different ways, but getting tripped up on this seemingly simple thing. Would love some help!

Comment: why use viewbag?  i find it very rarely necessary.

Answer (score 10):

```
ViewBag.Autobots = new Autobots[2];
```

then as per your code you can start to assign values to it:

```
ViewBag.Autobots[0].FirstName = "Bumble"
ViewBag.Autobots[0].LastName = "Bee"
ViewBag.Autobots[1].FirstName = "Optimus"
ViewBag.Autobots[1].LastName = "Prime"
```